# How do I change the size of my footnotes and change my line spacing for my reference section?

Tags: footnotes, layout

Our school's manual of style mandates the following format for term papers. I am not able to understand how would to do the following

> 7. Endnotes/Footnotes: Single-line spacing; Times New Roman Font 10
> 8. Bibliography/References: 1-line spacing; Times New Roman Font 12
> 9. Beginning of paragraph (excepting the first paragraph following the title and the first two levels of subheading): Tab set at 0.3”

This is my preamble. Any help would be appreciated

```
documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\author{}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\title{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\linespread{1.5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Single line spacing (so to speak) is the default for LaTeX.  Alas, \footnotesize is used for other things than just footnotes.  You can try `\let\footnotesize=\normalsize` and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try along these lines:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace} % can change interline spacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0.3in} % indentation of first line of a paragraph
\usepackage{lipsum} % lots of text
\begin{document}
\section{First}
First paragraph.\footnote{\lipsum[1]}

\lipsum[1]
  \subsection{Sub}
  First paragraph.

  \lipsum[2]

\bgroup % start a group in order to keep spacing change local
\onehalfspacing  % or \doublespacing?
Bibliography

Entry 1

Entry 2

\egroup % end the group
\end{document}
```

I would really have appreciated a full MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `end{document}`) showing what you had tried so I didn't have to waste my time trying to invent what your document might in general look like. Note that the above is a very crude MWE especially regarding the "Bibliography".

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will keep this in mind the next time I ask.Apologies. I also didn't understand the part about footnotes

Comment: @RadDragon What don't you understand about footnotes? In a `12pt` document footnotes are set in `10pt`. You haven't bothered to extend your original MWE so I don't understasnd your problem. --- GOM

Comment: Apologies. Have added all of the code now